# programming custom functionality into Verifone or Ingenico - where to find SDK?

Tags: point-of-sale, verifone

I'm trying to get my hands on some low-end Verifone or Ingenico terminals for a custom e-voucher application. I found the devices at the right pricing and with the right functionality, but I'm quite dazzled because I can't find any information anywhere about how to program custom functionality into these things?!

I hope I'm not into NASACIATOPSECRET land now? Or maybe we're supposed to purchase SDKs or whatnot?

The farthest I got was some file listings on VeriFone's site that require login for download but I can't find any signup link.

Would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the Mx800 series of devices you're going to need the [programming guide](http://support.verifone.com/fstore/0a463145bbfccb42_1656b33_139d7f3f73d_-5c7c/MX800%20Programmers%20Guide.pdf) as well as FormManager (in their Mx800 Integration Kit) to actually create the UI. Unfortunately I think they only grant access to that portal for folks that are either registered Enterprise customers or go through their certification program.

Comment: Which is quite stupid in my opinion since it's likely for the main reason for this to be related to their devices security......